# ASP.NET update labels separately and asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

Ok so I can successfully update my page labels asynchronously using a timer. The problem is that the labels always update simultaneously while I want each one to update in sequence.

Here is my aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1" 
  UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <contenttemplate>
     <asp:Timer id="Timer1" runat="server"
        Interval="5000" 
        OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
     </asp:Timer>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" >Label1</asp:Label>
     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" >Label2</asp:Label>
  </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

And my codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : Page
{

 public int counter = 0;

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Counter: " + counter);
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        Label1.Text = "<font color='green'>Started</font>";
        UpdatePanel1.Update();

    }
    if (counter == 2)
    {
        Label2.Text = "<font color='green'>Started</font>";
        UpdatePanel1.Update();

    }

}
}
```

After trying several examples I decided to ask here and see if I was missing something obvious. Somehow my counter variable is being reset to 0 which tells me that the entire page may be being rerun each tick instead of just the Timer1_Tick method.

Comment: Does it ever enter _if(counter == 2)_ condition?

Comment: Yes it does however both labels are updated at the same time instead of one 5sec after the other.

Comment: Update: After some reading, I see now that, due to the stateless nature of web applications, that each tick of the timer discards all of my variables and I need to figure out how to pass my counter along to each new session.

Answer (score 0):

The clause where `counter == 1` also increments `counter`, so by the end of the clause, `counter` = 2, hence the other condition is also true.

Don't increment `counter` within the `counter == 1` clause.

Comment: Yes thank you that was an obvious error probably made because I was just trying different things. However I still have the same problem. The Entire page seems to be reloading every tick of the timer causing my counter to reset to 0 each time.(question edited)